# Inserting date format in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, date, phpmyadmin, insertion

When I try to insert a row in a table in phpmyadmin, that has a date column with the format 'yyyy-mm-dd', it will show up like this:'0000-00-00'. What should I do?

First, I wanted to change the date format, but I gave up on that. Now, I'm focusing on trying to insert my data in phpmyadmin.

Comment: `yyyy-mm-dd` is the correct format. Make sure you put it in quotes, too. Please show your query.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that this question has both php and phpmyadmin tags. Are you writing a PHP program that inserts a row into MySQL or using phpMyAdmin's interface to do so? You're also too vague about your actual data, you could just have a silly typo.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.